# NLP Project on Multiclassification

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp

I am fresher and i am working on multi classification project in my organization i am unable to get good accuracy… the project is basically a email classification into 60+ teams… But the input data is into various language can be german , english, spanish likewise, Is anyone can guide me to get the output of the project.